# Phonegap : Page offset permanently after clicking on some element on Android Devices

Tags: android, cordova, offset

In my phonegap application, when I click on some textbox or, dropdown menu, the entire page is shifting right with some offset. And it becomes permanent. Its hampering my Application UI heavily.

Please, help me out.
A heartily thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Issue has been resolved by styling the div(Whatever be applicable) with 
  ***{top:0; left:0; }***